# Query Posts from Custom Field Value Taxonomy Set by Admin

Tags: php

In my custom post type, I want to allow the "admin" to pull related posts from another custom post type taxonomy. The admin should be able to put the taxonomy in a custom field and this will query posts from the taxonomy they choose.

The custom field is "featured_product_tag" - in the field a taxonomy from the "products" post type will be pulled.
Why doesn't this work? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
 $foo = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured_product_tag', true );
```

does echo the correct taxonomy but it doesn't pull from this taxonomy.

```
<?php 
$foo = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured_product_tag', true );
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'products',
    'taxonomy' => $foo,
    'order'    => 'rand',
    'showposts' => '4'
    );              
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
$url = $thumb['0'];
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
<div class="related-featured">
<img src="<?=$url?>" style="max-height: 180px;" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<span class="small-text-p"><i>from</i> <?php  echo  get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'price_low', 'true'); ?></small>
</div></a>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is there **WooCommerce** plugin installed ?

Comment: No - this is just in the custom post type named "products" - with the custom taxonomy "cosmetics" attached to it. I want to query 4 random products when the admin adds the "taxonomy" in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant run query based on **taxonomy** only. You also need to provide the taxonomy term the custom post type post associated with. Change your `$args` like below -

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'products',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cosmetics', // your taxonomy
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => get_term_by('name', $foo, 'cosmetics')->term_id, // your taxonomy term id or array of id's
        )
    ),
    'order'    => 'rand',
    'showposts' => '4'
);
```

For more information on `WP_Query()` arguments please [read this](http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/).

Comment: Can I know why you've remove acceptance ?

Comment: You've to save the taxonomy term as post meta or you need save both taxonomy and taxonomy term to post meta. Then pass the taxonomy and taxonomy term to the next query and you'll get the data. Hope I made myself clear. You can't query posts based on taxonomy.

Comment: Did you see my edit? It's not pulling anything. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: I have a taxonomy "tax1" with 4 posts in the tax. I go back to the post and add "tax1" in the field "featured_product_tag", from this, it should query 4 posts from "tax1" category. The taxonomy term is already in the post meta.

Comment: Then replace the `$foo` with taxonomy name and replace the `$term_id` with `$foo`. And you'll get data. Try it and then let me know.

Comment: 'taxonomy' => $foo - but $foo is being pulled from the custom field post meta. Sorry.

Comment: 'taxonomy' => $foo, // your taxonomy
           'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $foo, // your taxonomy term id or array of id's

Comment: What happened ?

Comment: Well I understood what happened. Can you please give me your taxonomy name ? It's a string like 'category' or 'post_tag' and its must have to be in lower case and unique. It can't be 'category'. It's already been taken. So find your taxonomy name and give it to me.

Comment: Post Type is: products

Comment: Custom taxonomy attached, = cosmetics

Comment: The Tax name: Skincare

Comment: "Skincare" is added manually by the admin. they would put "Skincare" in the custom field and it will query posts from the "Skincare" taxonomy, which is a custom taxonomy "cosmetics" attached to post type = products.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Just copy and paste it. Replace your `$args` with this `$args`.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your time & help @the_dramatist  - Much appreciated!